# Change a dropdown field selection to #333 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown field that has placeholder text and a few options to select after clicking on it. Originally, the placeholder text was #333, as was the options to select. I successfully changed the placeholder text to light grey by using the following code:

```
#estimation_popup select  {
   color: #b2b7c8 !important;
}
#estimation_popup select option {
   color: #000000!important;
```

Here is a visual to show the result:

[image]

The issue is however, that after an option has been selected, the color is light grey, when I want it to be #333. I understand why this is happening, but I think it is only possible to solve this using javascript, which I am not very good at.

Here is a visual to show what happens when an option is selected:

[image]

Please can someone help me change the selected value to #333.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **required** attribute on the select to select it when it is invalid. When you set the value of your placeholder option to "" you can select it with **:invalid**! Check this out:

```css
select {
  color: black;
}

select option {
  color: #333;
}

select:invalid, select option:disabled {
  color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<select required>
    <option value="" selected disabled="disabled">Click here to select</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">Not yet</option>
    <option value="2">Not sure</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, but like the answer above, would it be possible to insect that selected disabled part into the class using JS? I don't have easy access to the HTML code, but I do have a custom js area, hence why I was originally looking for a js solution :)

Comment: Sure! Use some DOM manipulation library to do this easly! Post your actual code and I can help you!

Comment: forgot to mention your username, please can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the input to be #333. I don't think you need JS to do that. Just give the input a color: #333 using CSS. I hope I got your question right.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mydropdown {
   width: 240px;
   height: 40px;
   font-family: Open Sans;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #FFF;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-right: 30px;
   outline-color:lightgreen;
   color:#333;
}
  
.mydropdown select { color: black; }

.mydropdown option:not(:checked) { color: black; }
 
.mydropdown option:checked { color: black; }

.mydropdown option[disabled]:first-child { display: none; }
```

```html
<select class="mydropdown">
    <option value="0" selected disabled>Seach</option>
    <option value="1"> Result 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Result 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Result 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I cannot easily add that "selected disabled" part to the dropdown html. I do have access to a custom js area though, is it possible to append that to the class that holds the dropdown field? I think it is ".select.form-control".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change both option or select with CSS `color` property:

```css
select  {
  color: #333;
}

option {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="notyet">Not yet</option>
  <option value="hotsure">Not sure</option>
</select>
```

Comment: While that does work, it doesn't solve the issue. I want the placeholder text to be grey (which is the first option text), the dropdown options (options 2+) to be black, and then once one is chosen, that should also be black.